# Displaying first 5 results from query in one div and rest in another

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am developing a quiz application on CodeIgniter.
Randomly 25 questions are picked from the database and displayed to the user.

The following is my code:

```
 <?php 
        $i = 1;            
        echo form_open('Menu/submit_ans', array('name' => 'quiz'));
        foreach ($quiz_array as $q){?>
        <center class="Qcounter">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

        <h3>Question No. <?php echo $i?> </h3>
        <br>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><?php echo $q->ques;?></td>
        <input hidden name="qid[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $q->qid;?>">
        <input hidden name="uid[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $user['id'];?>">
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="1"></td>
        <td><?php echo $q->ans_1;?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="2"></td>
        <td><?php echo $q->ans_2;?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="3"></td>
        <td><?php echo $q->ans_3;?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="4"></td>
        <td><?php echo $q->ans_4;?></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

       </div>
       </center>
        <?php 
            $i++;

        }

        ?>

        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit!</button></a>
        <?php echo form_close();?>
        <button id="btn_next">Next</button>
```

I want to display the first 10 results on one div.
And when the user clicks the next button, it shows the next 10 results.
*(hiding the current div and showing the next one)*

I just want to know how I can break the results and limit to 10 questions per div.

Comment: Can you explain more for better understanding?

Comment: There are 25 questions. The query brings in 25 questions to display to the user.
I dont want to display all 25 together. I want to show it like 10, a button to hide the current 10 questions and show the next 10 and likewise remaining 5

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/slice/  :: Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of indices.

Comment: Use Ajax pagination what you think about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your HTML (created from a PHP loop).

**First**:
This HTML isn't perfectly valid.... Even if it may work.
Modern browsers *"patch"* this.
Or maybe you were a little fast on cut'n paste for the example...

Anyway, I added a missing `<tr>/</tr>` wrapper on your 1st row of each question's `<table>`.
I also added a missing `</div>` and `</center>` in that PHP loop.

```
<?php 
    $i = 1;

    foreach ($quiz_array as $q){ ?>
        <center class="Qcounter">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h3>Question No. <?php echo $i?> </h3>
                <br>
                <table>
                    <tr><!-- added -->
                        <td colspan="2"><?php echo $q->ques;?></td>
                        <input hidden type="text" value="<?php echo $q->qid;?>">
                    </tr><!-- added -->
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="1"></td>
                        <td><?php echo $q->ans_1;?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="2"></td>
                        <td><?php echo $q->ans_2;?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="3"></td>
                        <td><?php echo $q->ans_3;?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="4"></td>
                        <td><?php echo $q->ans_4;?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div><!-- added -->
        </center><!-- added -->

        <?php 
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

So now that this is consistent...
Why not use the `<center>` tag as a wrapper to count questions on jQuery-side?

I added a class to it : `class="Qcounter"` which will only be used as a jQuery selector.

The function sets `display` onload for a given number of elements.
Then sets a click handler for a `someNextBtn` button id.

```
// Define the amount of question to show.
var showNquestion = 5;

// onload...
$(".Qcounter").each(function(){

    // Question indexes 0 to showNquestion will show.
    if( $(this).index() < showNquestion ){
        $(this).css({"display":"block"});
    }else{
        $(this).css({"display":"none"});
    }
});

// On "Next" button click.
$("#someNextBtn").click(function(){

    var lastShown=0;

    // Find the last question index shown.
    $(".Qcounter").each(function(){
        if( $(this).css("display") == "block" ){
            lastShown = $(this).index();
        }
    });

    $(".Qcounter").each(function(){

        //Question indexes "last+1" to "last+showNquestion" will show.
        if( ($(this).index() > lastShown) && ($(this).index() < lastShown+showNquestion) ){
            $(this).css({"display":"block"});
        }else{
            $(this).css({"display":"none"});
        }
    });

    if( lastShown == $(".Qcounter").length ){
        alert("You answered all questions.");
    }
});
```

**NOTICE** that `<center>` elements are checked for their `.index()`.
So it is indicated to wrap your whole set of questions within a `<div>` without any other elements, before or after, to prevent messing up that count.

Comment: Brilliant. The initial number of questions to be displayed is working brilliantly. But when I press next, the other questions are not displayed and I get an empty div.

Comment: I fixed some conditions... a couple minutes after posting. Did you use what's actually there ? You can check edit diffs with a click on "edited XX mins ago".